# How "cms_block_store" and "cms_page_store" tables are working with Primary keys in Magento?

Tags: magento2, database, cms-block, cms-pages, foreign-key

I have a general doubt in MySql foreign key constraints and Magento.

As per MySql, a table should have only one primary key for a table and a Primary key should contain unique values.

I checked in "cms_block_store" and "cms_page_store" Magento tables. In that, both table  block_id, page_id, and store_id columns are declared as foreign keys and at the same time mentioned as primary keys.

Here two primary keys declared in a table and
A foreign key cannot contain unique values but at the same time A primary key should contain unique values, but here the fields are working with the duplicate entries even the fields are mentioned as Primary keys.

Please check the attached screenshots:

`"cms_block_store"` table structure:

[image]

`"cms_page_store"` table structure:

[image]

Can someone help me to understand how working in Magento against MySql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can see the table create-query by running the query in Mysql console `show create table cms_page_store`.

```
CREATE TABLE `cms_page_store` (
  `page_id` smallint(6) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Store ID',
  PRIMARY KEY (`page_id`,`store_id`),
  KEY `CMS_PAGE_STORE_STORE_ID` (`store_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `CMS_PAGE_STORE_PAGE_ID_CMS_PAGE_PAGE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`page_id`) REFERENCES `cms_page` (`page_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `CMS_PAGE_STORE_STORE_ID_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='CMS Page To Store Linkage Table'
```

We can see **PRIMARY KEY (`page_id`,`store_id`)** in the above results. Also, we can see the same in `desc cms_page_store`.

[image]

**Can I have multiple primary keys in a single table?**

A Table can have a **Composite Primary Key** which is a primary key made from two or more columns. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE userdata (
  userid INT,
  userdataid INT,
  info char(200),
  primary key (userid, userdataid)
);
```

**Easy for your reference:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/217952/5528059
https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/2007/08/23/composite_primary_keys/